# Moving current employer 401(k) balance into self-directed solo 401k?

Tags: united-states, 401k, rollover, solo-401k, transfer

Let's say my employer offers a 401(k). In general, this means I can only pick from a basket of funds to invest in.

I prefer self directing my investments, and my broker offers a no-fee solo 401k.

I understand that contributions to a solo 401k are only intended to come from self-employment, which I do from time to time, so I am eligible to have such an account. This question is not about contributions.

Rather, can I move/transfer my current employer 401(k) balance to a self directed solo 401k while still remaining employed by them? Legalese aside, this is essentially a balance transfer, and I most likely will continue contributing to the employer 401(k).

But, all of the literature I can find online about this is related to "previous" employers and converting to IRAs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Not likely.
You usually cannot transfer your 401(k) out of a company plan while you are still working there. Some companies do permit such transactions for those 55 and older, but only for your own deposits, not for the matching portion, if any. 
Either way, best to ask the admin for your company plan.

If you were no longer with the company, you'd be able to transfer the 401(k) to your Solo 401(k) if you wished, either directly, or stopping thru an IRA.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to ask the 401k administrator.  _Some_ employers (usually with high-earning salaried employees) offer self-directed investments for 401ks through a brokerage in lieu of the usual mutual fund investment options. In one  such plan (in fact the _only_ such plan) whose details I am familiar with (though not as a participant), the 401k administrator was an expensive full-service brokerage firm that charged a large enough fee for opting for self-directed investments that it made no financial sense unless the 401k had about $500k or so available for investment.

Comment: My 401(k) offers a brokerage side. $80/yr fee plus $10 trades. We pretty much index in the 401(k) and if we feel compelled to buy individual stocks, use the IRAs.